# ResolveInfo.loadIcon causes ANR keyDispatchingTimedOut

Tags: android, android-package-managers

One of my class retrieves the list of the activities installed on the device and their icons. That works perfectly well on numerous phones but one of my users using a Nexus 7 got an ANR :

```
DALVIK THREADS:
(mutexes: tll=0 tsl=0 tscl=0 ghl=0)

"main" prio=5 tid=1 NATIVE
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x410a39a0 self=0x400d3010
| sysTid=15890 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1075213276
| state=D schedstat=( 2274319000 316147000 1599 ) utm=146 stm=81 core=0
#00 pc 00016d78 /system/lib/libc.so (read+12)
#01 pc 00012b3f /system/lib/libutils.so (android::ZipFileRO::mapCentralDirectory()+114)
#02 pc 00012fe7 /system/lib/libutils.so (android::ZipFileRO::open(char const*)+126)
#03 pc 0001765d /system/lib/libandroidfw.so (android::AssetManager::SharedZip::SharedZip(android::String8 const&, long)+92)
#04 pc 00018129 /system/lib/libandroidfw.so (android::AssetManager::SharedZip::get(android::String8 const&)+232)
#05 pc 000181e9 /system/lib/libandroidfw.so (android::AssetManager::ZipSet::getZipResourceTableAsset(android::String8 const&)+32)
#06 pc 00018a6d /system/lib/libandroidfw.so (android::AssetManager::getResTable(bool) const+124)
#07 pc 0006451f /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
#08 pc 0001e290 /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmPlatformInvoke+112)
#09 pc 0004d411 /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallJNIMethod(unsigned int const*, JValue*, Method const*, Thread*)+396)
#10 pc 000276a0 /system/lib/libdvm.so
#11 pc 0002b57c /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*)+184)
#12 pc 0005ff07 /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInvokeMethod(Object*, Method const*, ArrayObject*, ArrayObject*, ClassObject*, bool)+374)
#13 pc 00066f95 /system/lib/libdvm.so
#14 pc 000276a0 /system/lib/libdvm.so
#15 pc 0002b57c /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*)+184)
#16 pc 0005ff07 /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInvokeMethod(Object*, Method const*, ArrayObject*, ArrayObject*, ClassObject*, bool)+374)
#17 pc 000677e1 /system/lib/libdvm.so
#18 pc 000276a0 /system/lib/libdvm.so
#19 pc 0002b57c /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*)+184)
#20 pc 0005fc31 /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethodV(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, bool, JValue*, std::__va_list)+272)
#21 pc 000499fb /system/lib/libdvm.so
#22 pc 00046871 /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
#23 pc 00047533 /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::start(char const*, char const*)+390)
#24 pc 00000db7 /system/bin/app_process
#25 pc 0001271f /system/lib/libc.so (__libc_init+38)
#26 pc 00000ae8 /system/bin/app_process
at android.content.res.AssetManager.getStringBlockCount(Native Method)
at android.content.res.AssetManager.makeStringBlocks(AssetManager.java:257)
at android.content.res.AssetManager.ensureStringBlocks(AssetManager.java:249)
at android.content.res.Resources.<init>(Resources.java:189)
at android.app.ActivityThread.getTopLevelResources(ActivityThread.java:1705)
at android.app.ActivityThread.getTopLevelResources(ActivityThread.java:1734)
at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getResourcesForApplication(ApplicationPackageManager.java:746)
at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getDrawable(ApplicationPackageManager.java:636)
at android.content.pm.PackageItemInfo.loadIcon(PackageItemInfo.java:140)
at android.content.pm.ComponentInfo.loadDefaultIcon(ComponentInfo.java:161)
at android.content.pm.PackageItemInfo.loadIcon(PackageItemInfo.java:145)
at android.content.pm.ResolveInfo.loadIcon(ResolveInfo.java:186)
```

It seems like the ANR is caused by `ResolveInfo.loadIcon` when I try to retrieve the activity icon...
Any idea why it could be caused on one device and not others ? Maybe one of his app is not correctly installed or something like this...
Thanks for your time.

Comment: Are you calling the `ResolveInfo.loadIcon()` inside of a `Thread`,`Runnable`,`AsyncTask`, or `Service`? If you are not, it may be taking too much time on the main thread. This may only manifest on older, slower devices.

Comment: Yes I'm calling it from an other `Thread`, and using `Thread.join()` when having to display the data, that is to say much later. And the phone, is a Nexus 7 so I don't think it's any performance issue :/

Comment: Ok... I was calling `Thread.run`instead of `Thread.start` --' problem solved I guess.

Comment: Hmm. Not sure how long it would have taken me to spot that and not totally sure why it caused the problem. Must be a difference in the phone's Thread implementation. Sorry I couldn't be more help.